# How to upload Click conversions using the Google Ads API Rest Interface

Tags: rest, google-ads-api

I am trying to track a Click conversion with Google Ads using the Rest API but I can't find any helpful resources.

Right now the user flow looks like this:

User clicks on Ad -> User opens Website -> User downloads the Flutter App (gclid will be passed via dynamic links) -> User Signs up -> New Customer.io Event will be triggered (contains gclid) -> Upload conversion to Google Ads

The problem lies with the last step. In customer.io I can only use a Rest Call to upload the converion to Google Ads. I cannot use the client library of Google and I can't figure out from the documentation which call exactly I have to make here.
(Unfortunatly Google itself is advising against using the Rest API but also states that it is possible by itself. Also I don't have any other options here than going the route via Customer.io and making the Rest Call)

I would really appreciate any kind of help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer, because the other link is dead.

POST:[https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers/{customerId}:uploadClickConversions](https://googleads.googleapis.com/v15/customers/%7BcustomerId%7D:uploadClickConversions)

Where {customerId} is the customer performing the upload.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v13/customers/uploadClickConversions

Answer (score -1):

Method: customers.uploadClickConversions
Processes the given click conversions.

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v12/customers/uploadClickConversions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33271849)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).